# Windows tail a log file with jq

Tags: powershell, tail

I am using Windows 10 Powershell.

I want to tail a log file which is in JSON format and I also want to pick specific json fields.

Example logfile:

```
{"msg":"abc def1","time":"20:08","notneeded1":"xyz","notneeded2":"xyz"}
{"msg":"abc def2","time":"20:09","notneeded1":"xyz","notneeded2":"xyz"}
{"msg":"abc def3","time":"20:10","notneeded1":"xyz","notneeded2":"xyz"}
```

...

I can tail a log file live with Wait flag : Get-content -tail 10 -Wait 'C:\Desktop\data.log'

I can pick specific json fields via jq : Get-content -tail 10 'C:\Desktop\data.log'|jq '.time,.msg'

However I cannot use -Wait and jq together. Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: I have also tried this but it does not work: Get-content -tail 10 -Wait 'C:\Desktop\data.log' | ConvertFrom-Json | select time, msg

Comment: Works for me.  How is the file being written to?  Oh I'm in powershell 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own function to handle the powershell pipeline. Naturally you'll need to update the path to your jq file.

```
Function JQ {
    Param([parameter(valuefrompipeline)]$line)

    begin{
        $jq = "C:\temp\jq-win64.exe"
    }
    process{
        $line | &$Jq '.time,.msg'
    }
}

Get-Content $jsonfile -tail 10 -Wait | JQ
```

You could extend that by parameterizing the properties you want but this should get you started.

Comment: That works with JQ, thanks Doug. I tried to do the same with this `Function parse {
    Param([parameter(valuefrompipeline)]$line)

    process{
        $line | &ConvertFrom-Json | select time, msg
    }
}`. But this one is failing, any suggestions?

Comment: I think it’d be better handled in a new question rather than comments. I’ll look into it and answer your question if possible.

Comment: Actually that worked too, my mistake. Thanks for the help.